# how to show an array as a string from new datatype in haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, when you pattern match you are forced to unpack-age like in this sample code

```
data Mlist a = Mlist [a]
instance Show a => Show (Mlist a) where
    show (Mlist xs) = show xs


m = Mlist [1, 2, 3]
```

then when I type `m` in the interpretor, I expect "{1,2,3}" but I get [1,2,3].
What is wrong here? I thought this would work because I am using the show function on xs.

Comment: Why do you expect `{1,2,3}`? You told it to use the normal list representation: `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: How do I get it to print as a string (and not as an array representation)?

Comment: @omega `show` does return a string. It is very unclear (to me anyway) what you're asking. Or why you'd expect `show` to give you a string that contains curly braces.

Comment: Does curly braces in Haskell mean something else, like not a standard array?

Comment: @omega Curly braces don't mean anything in Haskell. As I said, I have no idea why you'd expect them.

Comment: (Just rehashing what's been said already). `show [1,2,3]` is the *string* `"[1,2,3]"`. You define `show` for `Mlist`s by applying `show` to the underlying list. From where are the curly braces supposed to come?

Comment: Oh and I also want to point out that `[1, 2, 3]` is a linked list - not an array.

Comment: @omega Are you a non-native English speaker, and when you say “expect“, do you mean “want” instead of “anticipate”?

Comment: @omega, curly braces in haskell are only used to denote blocks (like in C), but this feature is used very rarely. Haskell does not have a special notion of arrays, and Haskell lists are written used square brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show` on lists always gives you a `String` that starts with `'['` and ends with `']'`. If you want `'{'` and `'}'`, just replace them.

```
instance Show a => Show (Mlist a) where
    show (Mlist xs) = concat ["{", init . tail $ show xs, "}"]
```